# Interfacing with the code which calls select()

Tags: haskell, signals, ffi

I'm writing a Haskell binding to some the library and there is a function `void foo()`, which calls `select()` inside. When i call this function from Haskell, that `select()` call starts to constantly return `EINTR`. This confuses library code and it starts looping forever.

In the `#haskell` IRC channel i've been told to run `foo()` from a bound thread. I've used `runInBoundThread` for this and now everything seems to work. But in some rare cases i'm getting `Alarm clock` message in the console (**Ok, i've found it means that app catches SIGALRM**).

I'm not sure it's proper way to handle this problem and i don't want to depend on `Control.Concurrency`. What should i do?

Comment: `Control.Concurrent` is part of the standard library -- depending on it is the same as depending on haskell.  Why don't you want to use that module?   (although I admit the alarm messages are weird, I've never seen that)

Comment: I hear GHC uses SIGALRM and SIGVTALRM internally for thread management. If foreign code thread is sensitive to these signals, you should block them for that thread. See e.g. `withRTSSignalsBlocked` from `Database.HDBC.MySQL.RTS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of **SIGALRM** was GHC's runtime using old codepath for managing timer stuff. This old codepath was turning on because GHC's configure script had sort of linuxism in its check for `create_timer()` function. Fixing it made GHC use the same mechanism that is used on all platforms, and eliminated the error in question.

Relevant commit: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/commit/edc059a425068f9bf4a60520e8d8906bc764e2b5

Answer (score 1):

n.m.'s comment is correct: the code in `withRTSSignalsBlocked` will hide signals from your ffi'd code: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC-mysql/0.6.6.1/doc/html/Database-HDBC-MySQL.html#v:withRTSSignalsBlocked

This should also eliminate the need for runInBoundThread, I think.

Comment: `withRTSSignalsBlocked act = runInBoundThread . alloca $ \set -> do ...` Hmm... okay, i'll try it nevertheless.

Comment: This didn't helped me. If i remove `runInBoundThread` and `pthread_sigmask` call on rhs of `finally`, it works. But it's totally wrong thing to do, if i understand it right.

Comment: Then, clearly, the action you're calling guarded by withRTSSignalsBlocked isn't the one that's causing the error, or it is doing something with lazy IO somehow. i.e. blocking the signals works, but they're getting caught somewhere else than in executing the action.

Comment: Okay, i've substituted `runInBoundThread` with `forkOS`, removed second `pthread_unmask` call and it worked. This costed me an ability to get return value of the foreign call, but i don't need it, fortunately. Still, it's sooo hackish ):